# Using the sendmail function to send an email through MATLAB

Tags: matlab, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send an email, using the MATLAB sendmail function. I have been following the instructions of the sendmail function analysis in Mathworks on this link: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/sending-email.html

The code which I used on the command window is the following:

```
setpref ('Internet','E_mail','myemailaddress@gmail.com');
setpref ('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com') ;
sendmail('emailofreceiver@gmail.com','texttobesent') ;
```

The message that I am getting after running those commands is the following:

> Error using sendmail (line 169)
>
> Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
>
> Connection timed out: connect

From what I understand I must change the arguments inside the second setpref function that I call, though I am not sure what exactly to include it them, based on the the gmail smtp port that is returned.

Comment: I've neer used that, but shouldn't you enter a password in preferences as well?

Comment: In fact, the `sendmail` function (line 76 in R2016b) calls `getpref('Internet','SMTP_Password','')`, so you should probably set the password as `setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password','mypassword');`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. I tried doing this as well, but I got the same message from MATLAB.

Comment: @LuisMendo i tried running these two commands:  `getpref('Internet',SMTP_Username','myusername');` as well as `getpref('Internet','SMTP_Password','mypassword') ;` . But I still got the same result from MATLAB. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (Added these two commands on the already typed code)

Comment: No more ideas, sorry, I've never used `sendmail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Xiangru Li said on his answer, setting up related to SSL is indeed needed. But that was not enough. Eventually, I had to change my google settings to turn on access for less secure apps. Information about doing this can be found in this link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

So after doing this, the following code was successful and I managed to send an email with it:

```
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');  
setpref('Internet','E_mail','myemailaddress');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username','myusername');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password','mypassword');
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');

 props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class','javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');

props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');
sendmail('emailofreceiver','testtobesent') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to set up something related to SSL. Try to add following besides SMTP_Username and SMTP_Password, and it should work for gmail:

```
props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth', 'true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class', 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback', 'false');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port', '465');
```